# Guzzle 6: upload files with array data

Tags: php, arrays, guzzle6

I have to send array data with files. Using just data work properly:

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'form_params' => [
        [
            'data' => ['id' => 1234, 'name' => 'nombre'],
            'valid' => true
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But since I can't use "form_params" with "multipart", how can send files with arrays and boolean data?

I've tried:

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data',
            'contents' => ['id' => 1234, 'name' => 'nombre'],
        ]
        [
            'name'     => 'valid',
            'contents' => true,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

but I get a error since "contents" doesn't accept boolean or array values.

I need some help.

Thanks

**Update**:
I couldn't solve the problem and finally I had to user a not very nice solution, including as query string the form filed parameter and using just Multipart. Something like:

```
$client->post('http://xxx?id=1234&name=nombre', [
'multipart' => [
    [
        'name'     => 'myfile',
        'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
    ],
],
```

]);

Comment: I am fighting this problem myself. I got array data covered by setting               [headers] => [ [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded ]. But I cannot get a file to pass with this data. See this issue about array's as values of contents https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1177

Answer (score 5):

According to the Guzzle documentation:

> The value of multipart is an array of associative arrays, each
>   containing the following key value pairs:
>
> - name: (string, required) the form field name
> - contents:    (StreamInterface/resource/string, required) The data to use in the    form element.
> - headers: (array) Optional associative array of custom    headers to use with the form element.
> - filename: (string) Optional    string to send as the filename in the part.

So it looks like it's only accepting strings for the content (either directly or as a stream).  Their probable rational is that since it's a multi-part form you'd send each data point separately, as shown below...

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'id',
            'contents' => '1234',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'name',
            'contents' => 'nombre',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'valid',
            'contents' => 'true',
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Without knowing how the data is being parsed I can't say for sure this would be a viable option, but since it accepts custom headers you can send it as a JSON array (in string form) and then set the content type:

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data',
            'contents' => '{"id":1234, "name":"nombre"}',
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'text/x-json']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'valid',
            'contents' => 'true',
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Another option is using cURL directly, though I'm sure you wanted to avoid that since you are using Guzzle.

**UPDATE**

This isn't something I've tested personally, but here is one other thing you can try... (I should have thought of this first actually).

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data',
            'contents' => 'id=1234&name=nombre',
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'valid',
            'contents' => true,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jabari, your first option is not possible since I need send an array with "data" key, second one I already tried and 3rd one doesn't work. The only possibility is sending "form_param" option... Is there any way to send files inside "form_params" option? Thanks again

Comment: @Averias I'll do some testing later today, I'm interested in getting this working as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is a option to send upload files and array data together via Guzzle but in changed form:

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'myfile',
            'contents' => fopen('my_file.txt', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data[0][id]',
            'contents' => 1234,
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data[0][name]',
            'contents' => 'nombre',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data[1][id]',
            'contents' => 2222,
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'data[1][name]',
            'contents' => 'nombre2',
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'valid',
            'contents' => true,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

On the other side you can fetch data with `$_POST['data']` and then do the foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $data) {
    echo "Id: ".$data['id'];
    echo "Name: ".$data['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a recursive method that gets your array of data and prepares the multipart array:

```
private function prepareMultipartParams($params, $baseKey = null): array
{
    $result = [RequestOptions::MULTIPART => []];
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $key = $baseKey == null ? $key : "{$baseKey}[{$key}]";
        if (is_array($value))
            foreach ($this->prepareMultipartParams($value, $key) as $array)
                $result[RequestOptions::MULTIPART] = array_merge($result[RequestOptions::MULTIPART], $array);
        else
            $result[RequestOptions::MULTIPART][] = [
                'name' => $key,
                'contents' => $value instanceof UploadedFile ? fopen($value->path(), 'r+') : $value
            ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```